# What's the translation of “hoon" in French?

Tags: traduction, transports

A hoon [is a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoon):

> [in Australia and New Zealand] person who deliberately drives a vehicle in a reckless or dangerous manner, generally in order to provoke a reaction from onlookers.

What's the translation of “hoon" in French?

Comment: Ce phénomène est moins répandu en France, d'où la difficulté de traduction (!)

Comment: @A.G. There is no evidence this behavior is more common in AUS / NZ or not. In any case, there are certainly places in France where it is quite common, especially suburban ones.

Comment: Great word, Can we first "translate it" into BrE or AmE or CAN E? Faut chercher dans:  Tout l'argot des banlieues (Editions de l'opportun, 736 p., 22,90 euros),

Answer (score 6):

That can be a *[**chauffard**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chauffard)* or an *amateur de [**rodéos urbains**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rod%C3%A9o_urbain)*.

As vc74 stated, there is also a emerging idiom describing this behavior, although not limited to a driving context, *[**kéké**](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/k%C3%A9k%C3%A9)*, possibly from the provençal [*càcou* / *quècou*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cacou) and their first variant *[kèk/cake](https://rmc.bfmtv.com/emission/dit-on-faire-le-cake-ou-faire-le-keke-les-avis-divergent-entre-jean-jacques-bourdin-et-son-invitee-1473975.html)*, all still used in south-eastern France to mean *frimeur* / *fanfaron*. It's sometimes written *[kakou](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/kakou/)* too.

A couple of examples:

- [Il voulait "faire le kéké" dans le village de Saint-Piat, il a été condamné](https://www.lechorepublicain.fr/saint-piat-28130/actualites/il-voulait-faire-le-keke-dans-le-village-de-saint-piat-il-a-ete-condamne_11521068/)
- [Faire « le kéké » au volant l’amène devant le tribunal de Châlons](https://www.lunion.fr/id49284/article/2019-03-13/faire-le-keke-au-volant-lamene-devant-le-tribunal-de-chalons)

***Chauffard*** doesn't necessarily imply "to show off" so we can also say *un **chauffard qui se la pète** / ...**qui fait le malin***.

There is also the word *un [m'as-tu-vu](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/m%E2%80%99as-tu-vu)* (thanks @Laurent S.) that also means a show off leading to a possible *un chauffard m'as-tu-vu*.

Comment: @vc74 where do you live? Switzerland?

Comment: @vc In Marseille, that would be more *faire le càcou* or *faire le cake*.

Comment: Le chauffard est un conducteur dangereux qui met en danger la sécurité d'autrui, le plus souvent par la vitesse ou le non-respect des règles de circulation, mais il n'y a pas la connotation d'attirer l'attention à soi.

Comment: @A.G. Oui, j'ai proposé chauffard qui correspond à *deliberately drives a vehicle in a reckless or dangerous manner*. Qu'un chauffard le soit pour attirer l'attention ou pas est plus une question de psychologie que de linguistique, mais de toute façon, la question n'impose pas ce lien (*generally*, pas *always*).

Comment: Dans le cas où il le serait psychologiquement j'avais pensé à _(chauffard) exhibitionniste_ mais c'est simplement loufoque parce qu'on n'associerait jamais l'adjectif au comportement avec l'auto. _Tapageur_ marche pas vraiment non plus. C'est certainement un _amateur de manoeuvres périlleuses sur la voie publique_. Quand j'ai lu _hoon boating_, j'ai compris qu'on pourrait peut-être faire référence au son fatigant avec _vroum-vroum_ substantivé. Autrement il me semble que communément je décrive ça comme un _clown_ ou _bozo en char_, ça ressemble à _mariole_ d'une autre réponse, que j'aime bien.

Comment: @némésie-t-île Oui,  j'aime bien ton *vroum vroum*. Faire le mariole et associer un qualificatif à *chauffard* m'a inspiré deux autres propositions.

Comment: Not sure if this is a belgicism, but we also have "faire le m'as-tu-vu". There's even a famous public place in Knokke called "Place m'as-tu-vu" (and even though it's not the official name, you can even find it when searching in Google Maps... But I'll upvote this answer for "faire le kéké", which I use frequently, being understood by people from my age (in the 40's), less by people from older generations

Answer (score 3):

I am a native from South East France. A kéké or cacou has nothing to do with chauffard or driving in general. It's used to design a male show-off, someone who will do everything to impress those around him, especially girls. A kéké often tries to pass off for a bad guy just to be seen as as cool and virile.

Comment: OK, thanks for the rectification

Comment: I agree *càcou* has initially nothing to do with driving but that doesn't prevent someone to *faire le càcou avec son véhicule* which can match "hoon".

Comment: Sure, but the question was, what is a translation of "hoon". Not what word that means "show-off" could be used along with "car" to describe a "hoon".

Comment: Indeed, but the question is not either "What is not a translation of *hoon*". It would have been better for you to post your answer as a comment on my answer, or better, as a comment on the now deleted vc74 comment...

Comment: @Jiliagre, indeed you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne vois pas de traduction directe pour un comportement peu répandu en France. Je traduirais par une périphrase du genre

- Avec sa voiture, il fait le mariole pour épater la galerie
- Un fou du volant (expression un peu datée)

San-Antonio ou Audiard auraient certainement fait mieux :)